# 2 Accordions: How to style nav items(links) differently?

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

[Here](http://chesapeakepro.missionmedia.net/about) I have an accordion script styled correctly.  The nav item(link) that when clicked the text is grey & blue when active.  Further there is a black bar and two images for active & inactive (arrow pointing left & arrow pointing down when active).

[Here](http://chesapeakepro.missionmedia.net/articles) you see the same nav item styling but I need it to be just blue text no black bar no active/inactive arrows.

How do I create a 2nd styling for [this](http://chesapeakepro.missionmedia.net/articles) accordion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that you need to do is apply a different class to this toggler (example: `.toggler-2` instead of `.toggler`) and then in your css, style .toggler-2 exactly how you want it to look.

Comment: Actually, he states he only wants to change details in the design. So an alternative class .toggler + .secondary would be better because it would generate less CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the HTML code and write additional CSS for that section.

Additional class in CSS:

```
#dhtmlgoodies_listMenu.secondary a
{
    styling: goes here;
}
```

Changed HTML:

```
<ul id="dhtmlgoodies_listMenu" class="secondary">
```

Comment: thank you really appreciate the suggestion  :)   but i was talking about the accordion(s) on the left side.  It's css is .toggler.

Comment: Hmm okay. Well just replace the classes the code above. It's basically the same because what you we're actually asking is: how do I use alternative CSS for a secondary element.